# How to push Angular model to array while changing values using index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angularjs

I have an Angular Model and I am trying to push it to an array to create repeater fields. The array is then iterated to create html fields in a component. However, while pushing to the array, an undefined error is thrown [image].

Here is the Model code:

```
export class TierModel {
    feeName: string;
    feeDescription: string;
    unit: string;
    tierStart: number;
    tierEnd: number;
    rate: number;
};
```

And here is the code that pushes Model to array:

```
addForm()
  {
      const obj = new TierModel()

      obj[0].feeName = 'test';
      obj[0].unit = 0;
      
      this.dataarray.push(obj);
  }
```

The aim is to use an index with the object and then push it to the array so that any modification is to be done before pushing it to the array would be done here using index.

Any help would be more than

Comment: have you considered the initial situation where `this.dataarray` is empty? `newlen` would be -1 and `this.dataarray[0]` would be undefined

Comment: @Zerotwelve I have modified my question but the error is the same. Could you please check now?

Comment: it makes no sense to access `obj` with an index since it isn't an array.
use `obj.feeName = 'test';` or `obj["feeName"] = 'test'; instead

Comment: @Zerotwelve But what should I do if I need to push multiple feeName and unit?

Comment: then you call `addForm()` again and another object will be created/added.
maybe you should explain you problem/goal more precisely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all messed up,

There is no `obj[0]`, `obj` is not an array, its an instance of class, that has no constructor.

And pay attention to types, you are defining `unit` as `string` but giving it value of `number`.

Additionally, you dont even need to export class for this. Creating something with `new <class>()` is confusing when in reality its just an object. If you are declaring object you need to see `{}`, this is how you make it understandable for anyone on the first look.

This is how you do what you are trying to do

```
export interface TierModel {
  feeName: string;
  feeDescription: string;
  unit: number;
  tierStart: number;
  tierEnd: number;
  rate: number;
}


export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  objArray: TierModel[] = [];

  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.addForm();
    console.log(this.objArray);
  }

  addForm() {
    let obj = <TierModel>{};
    obj.feeName = 'aaa';
    obj.unit = 1;
    this.objArray.push(obj);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Accepting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

try the following

```
addForm()
{
    const obj = new TierModel()
    obj.feeName = 'test';
    obj.unit = 0;   
    this.dataarray.push(obj);
}
```

your const obj is an object so there is no need for obj[0].

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply but what if I would have to push multiple feeName and unit to the same array with different values? Should I have to use indexing or will it work without indexing as you have suggested?

Comment: for multiple values you can create new TierModel and again push it to the array, there is no need for indexing